# Detecting frame drops during screen capture

Tags: c#, screen-capture, sharpdx

I'm using SharpDx to capture the screen (1 to 60fps). Some frames are all transparent and end up getting processed and saved by the code.

Is there any simple/fast way to detect these frames drops without having to open the generated bitmap and look for the alpha values?

Here's what I'm using (saves capture as image):

```
try
{
    //Try to get duplicated frame within given time.
    _duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(MinimumDelay, out var duplicateFrameInformation, out var screenResource);

    //Copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU. 
    using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
        _device.ImmediateContext.CopySubresourceRegion(screenTexture2D, 0, new ResourceRegion(Left, Top, 0, Left + Width, Top + Height, 1), _screenTexture, 0);

    //Get the desktop capture texture.
    var mapSource = _device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(_screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None); //, out var stream);

    #region Get image data

    var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var boundsRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

    //Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap.
    var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    var sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
    var destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;

    for (var y = 0; y < Height; y++)
    {
        //Copy a single line 
        Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, Width * 4);

        //Advance pointers
        sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch);
        destPtr = IntPtr.Add(destPtr, mapDest.Stride);
    }

    //Release source and dest locks
    bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);

    //Bitmap is saved in here!!!

    #endregion

    _device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(_screenTexture, 0);

    screenResource.Dispose();
    _duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();
}
catch (SharpDXException e)
{
    if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
        throw;
}
```

It's a [modified version from this one](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/f4fb0fe0f12e3edc4eda3f6307d135a66fa172cd/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture/Program.cs).

I also have this version (saves capture as pixel array):

```
//Get the desktop capture texture.
var data = _device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(_screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, MapFlags.None, out var stream);

var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];

//BGRA32 is 4 bytes.
for (var height = 0; height < Height; height++)
{
    stream.Position = height * data.RowPitch;
    Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(stream.DataPointer.ToInt64() + height * data.RowPitch), bytes, height * Width * 4, Width * 4);
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way of saving the screen capture as image and/or pixel array, but it's somewhat working.

Anyway, the problem is that some frames captured are fully transparent and they are useless to me. I need to somehow avoid saving them at all.

When capturing as pixel array, I can simply check the `bytes` array, to know if the 4th item is 255 or 0. When saving as image, I could use the `bitmap.GetPixel(0,0).A` to know if the image has content or not.

But with both ways I need to finish the capture and get the full image content before being capable of knowing if the frame was dropped or not.

Is there any way to know if the frame was correctly captured?

Comment: How is this code called? How do you limit the FPS to what can be physically supported?

Comment: It's getting called from a timer that runs with an interval chosen by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ignore frame drops, I'm using this code (so far it's working as expected):

```
//Try to get the duplicated frame within given time.
_duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(1000, out var duplicateFrameInformation, out var screenResource);

//Somehow, it was not possible to retrieve the resource.
if (screenResource == null || duplicateFrameInformation.AccumulatedFrames == 0)
{
    //Mark the frame as dropped.
    frame.WasDropped = true;
    FrameList.Add(frame);

    screenResource?.Dispose();
    _duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();
    return;
}
```

I'm simply checking if the `screenResource` is not null and if there are frames accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

You propblem boils down to you trying to do this on a timer. There is no way to guarantee a *minimum* execution time for every single tick/frame. And if the user picks a too high value, you get effects like this. At worst you might have ticks queue up in the EventQueue, until you run into a Exception because the queue is overfilled.

What you need to do is limit the rate to a *maximum*. If it does not work as fast as the user wants, that is the reality. I wrote some simple rate limiting code just for such a case:

```
integer interval = 20;
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);

while(true){
  if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //insert code here

    //Update next dueTime
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);
  }
  else{
    //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Just two notes:

- this was designed to run in a seperate thread. You have to run it as such, or adapt the Thread.Sleep() to your multitasking option of choice.
- DateTime.Now is not suited for such small timeframes (2 digit ms). Usually the returned value will only update every 18 ms or so. It actually varies over time. 60 FPS puts you around 16ms. You should be using Stopwatch or something similar.

Comment: Even if I set a maximum fps, will the frame always be captured? I can set the timeout to a higher value, but when the frames are returning always transparent, it is not throwing a timeout exception.

Comment: @NickeManarin: That is one of those things you can only find out by trying. As for exceptions, depending how the Timer raises the events, they might get swallowed. Mutlitasking and in particular Threading is notoriously good at swallowing Exceptions. Especially with such a "fire and forget" scenario as you got here. There are two articles that I link often on the mater. While you do not catch to wide, there are other issues: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET